# Webtool to get all the clickable elements based on id,tag or class

Tags: html, selenium, web

I am trying to make a web automation script in python, which will launch a browser login into the portal and click on few elements (buttons, pages..) based on the configuration supplied to the project.

I am using `selenium` and it has been working very good. But I am having few issues understanding the `html` of a page. I need to click on few buttons and pages but I am unable to find proper id, tag or a class of that particular elements as I am bit new to `html`.

Is there any tool available which I can download and it can list all the elements of a webpage based on id, tag class it is using. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Chropath - add to chrome :) 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo

You can write xpath's there and it shows You all of the elements it finds.